# Submit form in an iframe to a cross domain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I wrote a chrome extension which injects a toolbar on top of sites (say amazon.com) as an iframe at the top.

When the user click on the action button on the toolbar (inside iframe), it's basically a form submit action, with action pointing to my full site (on another domain).

It's working, however only inside the iframe. I'd like the whole page to redirect to my site, rather than the iframe.

Is there anyway to do that in extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iframe :

Same Origin Policy prevents you from doing this.

Unless you can hack/XSS the other site's files to inject the JS, you will have a hard time.

Now if you legitimately need to communicate with the other page, and you either have control of the other page or can setup it to communicate with your server, you can use window.postMessage, JSONP or even Ajax with CORS (latter 2 will be harder to pass dynamic content though). But I believe it is not the case.

else :
you can directly inject the js script in to the page itself by that you can handle all operations in the main page same as running something on chrome console.